# How to read stepcounter in app

Tags: android

I found this link (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) that describes all the sensor data available for us to use in android apps, but I cannot seem to find the pedometer that's present in for example the nexus 5. Any suggestions on how to read and access the pedometers data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. After searching the web a bit longer I found this other webpage from android.com that explains how to use the Step Counter sensor in any app. This is the link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this open source app that uses step detector:

https://github.com/tananaev/steps-navigation